# readfile indents the first line when displaying on my page

Tags: php, html, file-io, indentation

The problem I am having is that when I use readfile in php on my page, the first line of the text is indented. Is there a way to fix this without going way out of my way  or is this something that just has to be dealt with?

Below is both a snip of what is showing up and the code that is outputting this to my page. I have searched and can find nothing that would explain why this is happening.

**Screenshot:**

[image]]

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <pre>
        <?php
            $file = 'guestbook.doc';
            
            if (file_exists($file)){
                readfile($file);
            
            } else {
                echo "File cannot be read.";
            }
    
        ?>
    </pre>
    <p>
        <form action="GuestBook.html" />
            <input type="submit" value="Return to Name Entry" />
        </form>
    </p>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whitespace inside `<pre>` is not ignored. Put `<?php` right after it:

```
<pre><?php
```

Same with closing `?>`

Comment: Thank you very much. I appreciate the assistance. Worked like a charm.